# Is there a .push like feature to dynamically add values to an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

When working with `arrays` you can dynamically add new values to the array by using the `.push` method. Is it possible to do the same when using objects?

For example I have a text box and after the user has typed in something and click's add can you add the value to the object so it saves each one e.g

**Example:**

```
{
  message: "This is the first message",
  message: "This is the second message",
  message: "Third message etc"  
}
```

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        // var objArray = [];
        var objObject = {};


        $('#icecream').on('click', function() {
            $(this).animate({'height': '200px'}, 300);  
        });

        $('#add').on('click', function() {
            var value = $('#icecream').val();
            // objArray.push(value);
            // console.log(objArray);
            objObject = {
                message: value,
            }
            console.log(objObject);

        }); 

    });
```

Comment: `key` must be unique in Object

Comment: UM, that object is not what you think it is....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{
  message: "This is the first message",
  message: "This is the second message",
  message: "Third message etc"  
}
```

This isn't a valid object. You can't have the same property three times(the key must be unique).
 You may want an array instead:

```
var messageObj = { 
 messages: [
   "This is the first message",
   "This is the second message",
   "Third message etc"
]};
```

Adding a new message will be:

```
messageObj.messages.push("Forth message");
```

You can add properties dynamically to objects:

```
var obj = {};
var propName = "message";
var propVal = "This is a message";

obj[propName] = propVal;
console.log(obj); // { message: "This is a message" }
```

[`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/0qvxLsxn/).

Comment: Thank you, I will accept your answer when I can in a few mins :)

Answer (score 0):

I think all you're looking for is `objObjects.message='This is the second message';`

If you actually want to keep each one, maybe you need an array:

```
objObjects.messages = [
  'This is the first message',
  'This is the second message',
   // etc
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `data` is jQuery  `object`. `Object` must required `key` and `value` pair.

```
data.message = "This is the first message";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
objObject.message = "...";
```

Adding a property to the end of an object adds it as a variable in that object.